# Impressão usando Crystal Reports em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

Eu estou com dificuldade em imprimir usando Crystal Reports no WPF, eu uso o mesmo sistema de impressão para um outro sistema e funciona normal, mas nesse sistema está aparecendo o seguinte erro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu acredito que o erro esteja na fonte de dados que eu estou passando, pois se eu não envio os dados ele imprime normal...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DataSet

[image: DataSet]

Crystal Reports
[image: Crystal Reports]

Comment: O erro era referente ao VS2015, ele estava conflitando com a versão do Crystal Reports que eu estou usando... Como era um projeto pequeno, eu refiz ele no VS2012...

Answer (score 0):

O erro era referente ao VS2015, ele estava conflitando com a versão do Crystal Reports que eu estou usando... Como era um projeto pequeno, eu refiz ele no VS2012...